# How to get a list of html input values parsed to integers from a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, parseint

I am new to JavaScript & writing a program that takes a collection of HTML 
    input values and returning the sum.

I want to convert the data-type of the value from string to integer with a for loop, but am having issues.

```
for (i = 0; i < allInp.length; ++i) {
var integer = [parseInt(allInp[i].value, 10)];
console.log(integer[i]);
}
// should return something like "3, 4, 5"
```

I expect the values of allInp to be returned as integers but returns them as strings.

Comment: What is `allInp`? Please show us that part of code as well! And.... why do you wrap `integer` to an array?

Comment: You need to create a single `result` array before the loop, then fill it inside the loop (one index per iteration). Creating that array literal inside the loop doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the array outside the loop and use `push()`:

```js
let allInp = document.querySelectorAll("input");

var arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < allInp.length; ++i) {
   arr.push(parseInt(allInp[i].value, 10));
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="2" />
<input type="text" value="1" />
<input type="text" value="7" />
```

Comment: OP wants a list, not a sum?